# How can I filter an array using an array MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this array for example: `userList = ["azeaze51g51az", "azeaze451565"]` those are users `IDs`
I want to filter events document in my `DB` in `MongoDB`, but it always returns an `empty array`.

events:

```
"events": [
        {
            "color": "#2779DE",
            "user": [
                {
                    "_id": "6064d66bb82b773b9466ead6",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "606de2de03a4bb393cd46763",
                }
            ],
            "_id": "60a955a4c1709b32943d7230",
            "title": "aze",
            "description": "aze",
            "start": "2021-05-02T23:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2021-05-10T23:00:00.000Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
]
```

this is the code I'm using:

```
const events = await Events.find({
        user : { $elemMatch: {userList} }
    });
```

Comment: use `$in` operator `"user._id": { $in: userList }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$unwind` and afterwards use `$in`. Below is the sample query. check the online sample example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HFv0zGkzcfC)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$user"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "user._id": {
            $in: [
              "6064d66bb82b773b9466ead6",
              "606de2de03a4bb393cd46763"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```